# Access to kafka consumer group information within a seek

Tags: spring-kafka

We are looking to expose an endpoint that allows us to rewind and offset for a given topic and consumer group id.

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

@Autowired
private List<CustomKafkaConsumer> customKafkaConsumersCallbacks;

@PostMapping(path = "/admin/reset/{timestamp}")
public void send(@PathVariable long timestamp) {
    customKafkaConsumersCallbacks.forEach((consumer) -> {
        consumer.seekToTimestampWithConsumerGroupAndTopic(timestamp, "consumer-group", "getting-started");
    });
}
```

For a POC, I have added a CustomKafkaConsumer class (below). I added a method to perform a filter when seeking.
We perform a timestamp seek for a given topic, consumergroup. In one of our services we have two consumers for every
topic (green/blue) so we should be able specify which one by consumer group id.

See `seekToTimestampWithConsumerGroupAndTopic` below:

```
@Component
public class CustomKafkaConsumer extends AbstractConsumerSeekAware {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomKafkaConsumer.class);


    @KafkaListener(id = "getting-started", topics = "getting-started")
    public void receive(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String key, String obj,
                        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) Long timestamp,
                        ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord) {
        LOGGER.info("received payload='{}'", consumerRecord.toString());
        LOGGER.info("Received message timestamp: {}, date: {}", timestamp,
                Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime());

    }

    public void seekToTimestampWithConsumerGroupAndTopic(long time, String consumerGroup, String topic) {
        this.getCallbacksAndTopics().forEach((cb, topics) -> {
            List<TopicPartition> filteredTopics = topics.stream()
                    .filter(topic::equals)
                    .collect(toList());
            cb.seekToTimestamp(filteredTopics, time);
        });
    }
}
```

My question is, I'm not sure how to get access to the consumer-group information to be able to use within a filter inside seekToTimestampWithConsumerGroupAndTopic. I see the information is there on the callback object. But not accessible.

Wonder if you guys have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GaryRussell Would you mind taking a look at this question? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On thing you could do is override `onPartitionsAssigned()`; call `super.onPartitionsAssigned()` and then capture the  group using `KafkaUtils.consumerGroupId()` and store it in a map

```
private final Map<TopicPartition, String> groupForPartition = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

This assumes you are using the same listener instance for both containers; otherwise you could simply capture the group once per listener instance; you would not need to use a map.